# How to use SUBSTRING in OpenQuery - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, openquery

I have written an "open query" to fetch data from Proactive/Oracle DB

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (METER, 
   'SELECT 
         ME.Col1
        ,ME."ext"               AS ext         
        ,ME."t-date"                AS Date
        ,ME."per-id"                    AS Person
        ,PE."con-id"                AS Contact
        ,PE."add-id"                AS Address
        ,substring(SC."contact-title",0,10)         AS Member
        ,SC."given"             AS Giver
        ,SC."surname"               AS lastname 

    FROM PU."member" ME
        LEFT JOIN PU."personal" PE
          ON ME."per-id" = PE."per-id"
        LEFT JOIN PU."cont" SC
          ON PE."contactid" = SC."contactid"
```

its showing error as :

OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "NATE" returned message "[DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Bad arguments (7487)".

How can I write "SUBSTRING" for this column - substring(SC."contact-title",0,10)         AS Member

Please help

Comment: Since you are hitting an oracle DB I think you'll need `SUBSTR()`

Comment: SUBSTR() is also showing same error

Comment: Have you tried specifying the starting index as 1 instead of 0?